# SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal -Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo esse erro na seguinte função:

```
function formaQueryConta(cpf){

        var numConta= jsonDtContasCliente[(document.getElementById("listaContas").value)-1];
        console.log(typeof(cpf)); //Diz que é String
        console.log(typeof(numConta)); //Diz que é String
        var parms = "&cpf="+cpf"&conta="+numConta; //O ERRO É APONTADO NESTA LINHA
        ajaxCall("Persistencia.php?action=buscaConta" +parms, formaCanvas);

}
```

Não encontrei no Stack nada que me ajudasse. Alguma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta um `+` na concatenação:

```
var parms = "&cpf="+cpf"&conta="+numConta; //O ERRO É APONTADO NESTA LINHA
//                     ^---aqui
```

> Não encontrei no Stack nada que me ajudasse

Isso é normal, pois esse erro pode ser por diversos motivos e é mais ou menos genérico. Ele simplesmente indica que quando estava a construir a string encontrou algo que não estava à espera, neste caso o `"`.

O que eu aconselho para as próximas vezes e tentar ler a linha com calma e ter atenção a cada caratere.

Uma alternativa comum nos dias de hoje em ES6 é utilizar [*template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), que funciona como interpolação e que pessoalmente acho mais legível. Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```
var parms = `&cpf=${cpf}&conta=${conta}`;
```